# Is there a way to package tests in python

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest

In my CI/CD environment I have a multiple projects that use mostly the same tests, with a bit of variation. Since all of them are mostly the same, just different projects/builds use them a bit differently, I am looking for a way (if there is one) to package the tests themselves to pass around the projects. EDIT: Packaging tested code is not possible.

The ultimate usage will be something like this:

```
pip install <test-package> 
pytest -m <some-mark-depending-on-build/project> --<additional-variables>
```

Is there a way to do this?
EDIT: If there is, please point me out toward a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It surely is possible; however, applying the same tests to various projects is maybe a sign that some sort of module or library is begging to be abstracted from your projects?

Comment: You are correct. I want to abstract the tests enough to be usable where I need them. The jist is that similar tests might produce different results, depending on the application state, and this is exactly why I have a whole CI/CD setup for my application.

Comment: But then should not the code which uses these tests be a separate module with its own test suite? This sounds like you are copy/pasting code instead of setting it up for reuse.

Comment: @tripleee You are correct. I want to find a way to avoid it.

Comment: What I think we are trying to suggest is that the tests *and the code they are testing* should be a separate module.

Comment: Packaging the application and/or it's testable parts is not possible, due to multiple reasons. I just want to try to package the tests themselves.

Comment: Then maybe you are making this an XY problem? http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Definitely not. Please remember that apart from code decisions there are also marketing and/or long-term product vision involved.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it here for references.
The way to do this is to create a test package that can run as python module, from **main**.py.
After researching and some testing, I've concluded that in my case this will create more code to maintain than I would otherwise properly reuse.